# Getting error while executing python program to get a caller to conference call from twilio server

Tags: python-2.7, twilio, twilio-api, ngrok, twilio-twiml

I wrote a python program as to [Ph Num 1 <-> Twilio Server <-> Ph Num2 ]
[- Send a Message from my ph number (Num 1) containing another phone number(Num 2) to twilio server
- twilio takes the number (Num2) and calls me back (Num1) (saying as you are about to conference) and
- twilio calls the Num 2 and conferences me (Num1)

Here is my program:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from twilio import twiml
from twilio.rest import Client

app = Flask(__name__)

account = "AC7d2a***************"
token = "f83b27**************"
client = Client(account, token)

@app.route("/sms", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def sms():
    number=request.form["From"]

    call= client.calls.create(from_="+1857*******",to=number,url="https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/EHb330731ab2c9a35fcdc620bef1b88536")

    return str(resp)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run()
```

The url="https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/EHb330731ab2c9a35fcdc620bef1b88536 contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Say>You are about to enter a conference</Say>
  <Dial><Conference>number</Conference></Dial>
</Response>
```

i did Ngrok too and added my Ngrok link in Voice and Message URL in twilio number

I tried many changes and getting all kind of error instead of twilio number calling me after sending a message(with Ph Number (Num2) to conference)

Recent error while executing the above code is
**Error:**

```
[2017-11-13 09:46:41,570] ERROR in app: Exception on /sms [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/arif/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/arif/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/arif/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/arif/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/arif/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "conf.py", line 17, in sms
    return str(resp)
NameError: global name 'resp' is not defined
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Nov/2017 09:46:41] "POST /sms HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Does my program get the result what i expected ? Can anyone help me where is the issue is ?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There are a couple of issues here. First up, you are getting an error in your webhook response. You can see the error at the bottom of your stack trace:

```
  File "conf.py", line 17, in sms
    return str(resp)
NameError: global name 'resp' is not defined
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Nov/2017 09:46:41] "POST /sms HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

It says that `resp` is not defined.

You can see that within your method, you never define a `resp` but you try to return the `str` version of it:

```
def sms():
    number=request.form["From"]
    call= client.calls.create(from_="+1857*******",to=number,url="https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/EHb330731ab2c9a35fcdc620bef1b88536")
    return str(resp)
```

You can just return an empty string  to Twilio in this case.

```
def sms():
    number=request.form["From"]
    call= client.calls.create(from_="+1857*******",to=number,url="https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/EHb330731ab2c9a35fcdc620bef1b88536")
    return ('', 204)
```

Once that is fixed you'll find you are only making one call, the outgoing call back to yourself. To conference with the number that you want to call, you will need to generate two calls. You say that the body of the message that you are sending will be the other number you want to dial into the conference, so this should work:

```
def sms():
    my_number=request.form["From"]
    other_number=request.form["Body"]
    twilio_number="+1857*******"
    conference_url="https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/EHb330731ab2c9a35fcdc620bef1b88536"
    client.calls.create(from_=twilio_number,to=my_number,url=conference_url)
    client.calls.create(from_=twilio_number,to=other_number,url=conference_url)
    return ('', 204)
```

Let me know if that helps.